# Given that so many Indo-European peoples called themselves "Veneti" or the like, can we conclude that it was the endonym of PIE people as well?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, names

For instance:

Veneti (Gaul) - Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veneti_(Gaul))

Vistula Veneti - Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vistula_Veneti)

Adriatic Veneti - Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adriatic_Veneti)

Vends (Livonia) - Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vends_(Livonia))

Vandals - Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandals)

Vyatichi - Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyatichi) (< Proto-Slavic Ventichi), the Finnish name for Russia is still Venäjä – Wikipedia (https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ven%C3%A4j%C3%A4), and similar names in [Karelian](https://olo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ven%27a) and [Veps](https://vep.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ven%C3%A4ma) languages.

Vindelici - Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vindelici)

Eneti - Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eneti)

The word most likely comes from a PIE root meaning “braided ones” or another root meaning “love”.

Comment: Compare Lake Van? Berlin has a Wannsee, by the way, close to Babelsberg (with what looks like a crater sea), and Moabit, which I always found kinda lol, although *Wanne* "basin, tub" gives that one a reasonably synchronic etymology

Comment: Another curiosity to add to your collection [Vineta](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vineta), a legendary city at the mouth of river Oder that sank into the Baltic see. Note the different versions of the name, it could be as well that it was originally *Jumne* instead of *Vineta*.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think so.

It is plausible to assume that the Adriatic Veneti and the Vistula Veneti are connected or even the same people trading along the [Amber Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amber_Road) connecting the Baltic sea with the Mediterranean Sea. The Gaulish Veneti can well be an offshot of that population migrating together with Celtic people westward during the [Celtic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celts#Origins).

Vends, Vandals, and Vyatichi are attested several centuries later in approximately the same area where the Veneti once lived, but it is not clear how their names connect to them and at least for the Vandals, sound laws don't really fit. But we often see that old ethnonyms are transferred to a new population with a different language English speaking Britains and Romance speaking French are just two prominent examples for that.

The Eneti aren't attached to that cluster, but is there any evidence that their name once contained a /w/ sound (digamma)? And do we know anything about their language? Their linking to the Adriatic Veneti by Latin authors looks like an invention of tradition in order to give the Adriatic Veneti some mythological depth, the link is denied by the Greek historian Strabo.

Comment: Vyatichi once inhabited vast areas in Russia: basins of Don, Oka and Moscow region. Hardly they are connected directly to the Veneti in central Europe.

Comment: There are also several rivers with similar names: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venta_(river) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyatka_River, former name of Visla is Vandalus. At least former two seemingly come from the PIE root meaning "to wind, twist". So a river could get the name from its form, and the people could get the name from the river.

Comment: Naming the Visla river Vandalus is another case of invented history, related to the [Princess Wanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Wanda) mythos. Classical authors named that river Vistula.

Comment: And I agree, it is plausible to derive the name of a river from a root meaning "to wind, to twist".

Comment: Another river, in Romania: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vene%C8%9Bia